# Using LIKE operator to update a list of names

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I've been updating a dbo with the following code in SQL BigQuery, BUT I was wondering if there was a way to make it easier and more clean, instead of having to type `NAME LIKE "%TEXT%"`  for every word I am looking for.

```sql
UPDATE `dbo.Servcomp_Dataset.bankstatement`
SET Category = "Purchases" --, Subcategory = "Adm" 
WHERE (Name_payeeLIKE "%shipp%" AND Name_payee NOT LIKE "%Bank of%"  AND Name_payee NOT LIKE "%Mortgage%" AND Name_payee NOT LIKE "%Frigelar%" AND Name_payee NOT LIKE "%Delivery guarathon%" AND Name_payee NOT LIKE "%Strada%" AND Amount < 0 AND Category IS NULL )
```

Note that I use "`%TEXT%`" because some of the names I'm looking for are either in the middle or at the end.

Comment: Where is TEXT coming from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of your current where clause

```
WHERE Name_payeeLIKE "%shipp%" 
AND Name_payee NOT LIKE "%Bank of%"  
AND Name_payee NOT LIKE "%Mortgage%" 
AND Name_payee NOT LIKE "%Frigelar%" 
AND Name_payee NOT LIKE "%Delivery guarathon%" 
AND Name_payee NOT LIKE "%Strada%" 
AND Amount < 0 AND Category IS NULL
```

consider below

```
WHERE Name_payee LIKE "%shipp%" 
AND NOT REGEXP_CONTAINS(Name_payee, r"Bank of|Mortgage|Frigelar|Delivery guarathon|Strada")
AND Amount < 0 AND Category IS NULL
```